# In FreeMarker, how do I automatically convert a custom object (e.g. java.awt.Color) to a particular String value (e.g. HTML hex color)?

Tags: java, freemarker

In my data model, I have a lot of methods which return a color encoded as an [HTML color hex code](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colorvalues.asp) (e.g. #8da6b1).  These methods would be much simpler if they could simply return a [java.awt.Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) and let FreeMarker object wrappers take care of the conversion.  What do I need to add to FreeMarker's configuration?  Do I need to write a custom ObjectWrapper?  If so, what is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The FreeMarker Manual now has a better (more advanced) example of doing this kind of thing: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_objectWrapper.html#pgui_datamodel_customObjectWrappingExample. The important point there is that if you want to get back your `Color` (as oppsed to a `String`) when you pass it to a Java method in a template, then you have to implement `AdapterTemplateModel`, so `SimpleScalar` won't be good enough.

Extend `DefaultObjectWrapper` (or whatever `ObjectWrapper` you are using):

```
@Override
protected TemplateModel handleUnknownType(Object obj) throws TemplateModelException {
    if (obj instanceof Color) {
        return new SimpleScalar(toHTMLHexCode((Color) obj));
    }
    return super.handleUnknownType(obj);
}
```

where implementing `toHTMLHexCode` is left to you. Then where you set up the `Configuration` singleton, do `cfg.setObjectWrapper(new YourObjectWrapper(Configuration.VERSION_2_X_Y))`, or if you configure FreeMarker from `Properties`, then `object_wrapper=com.example.YourObjectWrapper(2.X.Y)`

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll try it out.  Why override handleUnknownType() and not wrap()?  Why pass the obj to wrap() if it isn't an instance of Color?

Comment: Updated my answer... calling `super.wrap` is not correct, of course it should be `super.handleUnknownType`. Why not just override `wrap`? You could, but then the wrapper couldn't deal with your type last.

Comment: Another thing... if you need to pass the color back to Java methods  from the template, then `SimpleScalar` is not good enough, as it can't be un-wrapped to `Color`, only to `String`. In that case the wrapped value need to implement both `TemplateScalarModel` (= FTL string) and `AdapterTemplateModel` (so that it can be un-wrapped to `Color`).